# Using Natbib and fixing some issues with References section

Tags: natbib

I am using the `natbib` package in my latex document. The bibliography style is `apalike`. The bib file contains the following two entries -- one is a journal article and another is a book, which all have original titles where first letters of words are capitalized. Also, both have `url` links. My latex document file is then placed below: it cites both of the sources, while the References section has some issues: (1) the title of the article does not capitalize the first letters of the words, (2) `url`s of these sources are suppressed and not shown. Is this possible to fix these two issues? Thanks!

```
@article{sen1979,
 ISSN = {00130133, 14680297},
 URL = {http://www.jstor.org/stable/2231867},
 author = {Amartya Sen},
 journal = {The Economic Journal},
 number = {355},
 pages = {537--558},
 publisher = {[Royal Economic Society, Wiley]},
 title = {Personal Utilities and Public Judgements: Or What's Wrong With Welfare Economics},
 urldate = {2024-01-19},
 volume = {89},
 year = {1979}
}

@book{beck2000,
  title={What is Globalization?},
  author={Ulrich Beck},
  year={2000},
  publisher={Polity},
  url={http://www.jstor.org/...}
}
```

Here is latex code of the simplified document:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{LaTeX References: the \textit{natbib} Package}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

Some text from \citep{sen1979}. Also from \citep{beck2000}

\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{Data/example} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: apalike is old and doesn't support url. Can't you use biblatex+biber? Unrelated: Remove the like `\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}`. utf8 is the default since 5 years anyway, and utf8x doesn't add anything useful nowadays.

Comment: unrelated but don't ue `[utf8x]` (it just produces a warning that itshould not be used)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Indeed, switching to biblatex seems a great idea. The only thing now I have an issue with `\addbibsource{../example.bib}` command. The issue is that my latex document and `example.bib` are in different folders on my PC's hard drive. With `natbib` this path worked well: `../example.bib`. It does not working this way with `biblatex`. What I am missing here? Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this is helpful:

**Content of BIB file**

```
@article{sen1979,
 ISSN = {00130133, 14680297},
 URL = {http://www.jstor.org/stable/2231867},
 author = {Amartya Sen},
 journal = {The Economic Journal},
 number = {355},
 pages = {537--558},
 publisher = {[Royal Economic Society, Wiley]},
 title = {{P}ersonal {U}tilities and {P}ublic {J}udgements: {O}r {W}hat's {W}rong {W}ith {W}elfare {E}conomics},
 urldate = {2024-01-19},
 volume = {89},
 year = {1979}
}

@book{beck2000,
  title={What is {G}lobalization?},
  author={Ulrich Beck},
  year={2000},
  publisher={Polity},
  url={http://www.jstor.org/...}
}
```

**TeX file start here**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\title{LaTeX References: the \textit{natbib} Package}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

Some text from \citep{sen1979}. Also from \citep{beck2000}

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{test} 
\end{document}
```

Here, have kept grouping for the capital letters and used the package `apacite` with the option `natbibapa`

[image]